# (Discord.js v13) Unable to fetch messages from channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js, fetch

*Node.js: v16.13.0* | *Discord.js: v13.3.1*

Hello, I've been getting trying to fetch all the messages from a channel. However, I get the following errors:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache')
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetch')
```

My code goes like this:

```
    if(message.content == "!q test")
{
    const channelS = client.channels.cache.get('880814576692789258')

    channelS.messages.fetch().then(messages => { //<---error here
        messages.forEach(msg => console.log(msg.content));
      });
}
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: What is `client`? Is this a command handler?

Comment: The error means that `cache` and `messages` are undefined, so I'm assuming either the channel doesn't exist or it's not a text channel. Try console.logging what client, client.channels, and client.channels.cache are.

Comment: The channel might not be cached in your client. Try to fetch the channels to update the cache.

Comment: `cache` shouldn't be undefined but an empty Collection though. If anything's not cached.